# Front-End input fields warning message if the field is not filled with information when submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

All I want is a small message to pop up on the corner of the site saying fields are not completed, like a small popup or a small window I tried to do this in JavaScript using alert but it makes my site slow very slow which is kind of annoying.

The form need to be filling

```
     <form>
                            <label class="name_label">Your Name</label>
                            <input type="text" id="name" class="name_input" required placeholder="write your name" autocomplete="off">
    
                            <br>
    
                            <label class="number_label">Phone Number</label>
                            <input type="tel" id="phone" class="number_input" required placeholder="Phone" autocomplete="off">
    
    
                            <label class="company_label">Company Website </label>
                            <input type="email" id="email" class="company_input" placeholder="shoesit.com" required autocomplete="off">
    
                            <div class="next-btn ">
                            <button type="submit" value="Continue" id="continue" value="click" onclick="vaildfunction()"> CONTINUE</button>
                            <a  id="nxt" onclick="Next()">Next</a>  
                            </div>
</form>
```

The JavaScript i'm using:

```
var x=0;
       function vaildfunction(){

         var name=document.getElementById("name").value;
         var phone=  document.getElementById("phone").value;
         var email=  document.getElementById("email").value;

         if(name=="") {
             alert("Please Fill your Form First");
         }
         else if(phone==""){
            alert("Please Fill your Form First");
         }
        else if(email==""){
            alert("Please Fill your Form First");
        }
        else{

            alert("Your form has submitted Sucessfully");
            x=1;
                }
       }      
       function Next(){
       if(x==1){
         window.location = href="thanks.html";
       }       
       else{
        alert("Please Fill your form first before you move on");
       } 
       }
```

Comment: first you need to edit your question. its not clear.
And for what you asked - you can get this result easily by including the field "required" as a attribute of each of the <input> elements that you want to required..

Comment: edited my question hope it's more clear now but what I want is a popup message or a small window saying there is an error that the fields are not filled yet

Comment: so if you want to get JS samples to your question - you have to include code sample of your situation.. edit again ;)

Comment: Edited again hope its more clear now

Answer (score 0):

this is more related to the HTML form. When You want to e.g. require an email form user, all You need to do is set an input type for email, and then when a user tries to send a form with a badly formatted email, he gets an error.
https://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

Comment: I want more like a small message like in the corner of the page to show and say please fill the empty fields

Comment: You have to create your own message div, style it a bit and add js to validate form.